# Laravel 5 configure timezone not define the timezone at postgres connection

Tags: laravel-5, timezone, postgresql-9.4, localtime

I have a question: How you usually work on timezone in the sites with laravel 5?

Postgres is in localtime and the local timezone of my notebook is in Brasilia. But the application is with the `config/app.php` set to UTC but the database configuration in `config/database.php` had no specification, so I passed the parameter to find `config("app.timezone")` which is `UTC`.

Then after login I print the `JWT CustomClaims` and the timezone of Brasilia comes to me. [0.o]

Running on the postgres clilent, I hedge the timezone to UTC and make the search for user data and it comes to normal. So this parameter in `config/database.php` is not solving.

Any tips?

Paste with the database.php configuration:

https://pastebin.com/Uq005TjT

Sistema: Debian Jessie

```
~$ timedatectl

    tosystems@debian:~$ timedatectl
      Local time: Thu 2017-04-06 21:16:55 -03
  Universal time: Fri 2017-04-07 00:16:55 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2017-04-06 21:16:56
       Time zone: America/Sao_Paulo (-03, -0300)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: yes
      DST active: no
 Last DST change: DST ended at
                  Sat 2017-02-18 23:59:59 -02
                  Sat 2017-02-18 23:00:00 -03
 Next DST change: DST begins (the clock jumps one hour forward) at
                  Sat 2017-10-14 23:59:59 -03
                  Sun 2017-10-15 01:00:00 -02

Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone. This
         mode can not be fully supported. It will create various problems with time
         zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC time is never updated,
         it relies on external facilities to maintain it. If at all possible, use
         RTC in UTC by calling 'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'
```

config/app.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'en',
```

config/database.php

```
<?php

    return [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Default Database Connection Name
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
        | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
        | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
        |
        */

        'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Database Connections
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
        | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
        | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
        |
        |
        | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
        | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
        | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
        |
        */

        'connections' => [

            'sqlite' => [
                'driver' => 'sqlite',
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
                'prefix' => '',
            ],

            'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
            ],

            'pgsql' => [
                'driver' => 'pgsql',
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'timezone' => config('app.timezone'),
                'locale' => config('app.locale'),
                'prefix' => '',
                'schema' => 'public',
                'sslmode' => 'prefer',
            ],

        ],
```

My timezone authenticated now:

```
array:1 [
  "user" => array:4 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Francis Rodrigues"
    "email" => "francis-01@tosystems.net"
    "last_logged_in_at" => Carbon {#236
      +"date": "2017-04-07 11:49:48.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 1
      +"timezone": "-03:00"
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have to set to a Timezone supported by PHP.

If I did not misunderstood, in your case, you're trying to set the timezone to Brazil.

This should work:

```
'timezone' => 'America/Brasilia'
```

Comment: In really, I'd like that application and postgres connection utilize UTC timezone and not my localtime of Brasilia.

Answer (score 0):

My provisory solution in User model:

```
    /**
 * Setting UTC timezone with mutator.
 *
 * @param $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastLoggedInAtAttribute($value)
{
    $carbon = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC(strtotime($value));
    return $carbon->toDateTimeString() . $carbon->getTimezone()->getName();
}
```

output in UTC timezone:

```
array:1 [
  "user" => array:4 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Francis Rodrigues"
    "email" => "francis-01@tosystems.net"
    "last_logged_in_at" => "2017-04-07 18:04:31+00:00"
  ]
]
```